# Memcached servers keeps failing

Tags: memcached, pylibmc

Everyday I get an error email from my python flask app with the following error:

```
WriteError: error 5 from memcached_set: (54648992) SERVER HAS FAILED
AND IS DISABLED UNTIL TIMED RETRY, host: 127.0.0.1:11211 ->
libmemcached/connect.cc:612
```

Memcached is running and the address is set up to 127.0.0.1 on both the client and the server. When I manually check connection it seems just fine. It only happens periodically.

~  cat /etc/memcached.conf:

```
# memcached default config file
# 2003 - Jay Bonci <jaybonci@debian.org>
# This configuration file is read by the start-memcached script provided as
# part of the Debian GNU/Linux distribution. 

# Run memcached as a daemon. This command is implied, and is not needed for the
# daemon to run. See the README.Debian that comes with this package for more
# information.
-d

# Log memcached's output to /var/log/memcached
logfile /var/log/memcached.log

# Be verbose
# -v

# Be even more verbose (print client commands as well)
# -vv

# Start with a cap of 64 megs of memory. It's reasonable, and the daemon default
# Note that the daemon will grow to this size, but does not start out holding this much
# memory
-m 64

# Default connection port is 11211
-p 11211 

# Run the daemon as root. The start-memcached will default to running as root if no
# -u command is present in this config file
-u memcache

# Specify which IP address to listen on. The default is to listen on all IP addresses
# This parameter is one of the only security measures that memcached has, so make sure
# it's listening on a firewalled interface.
-l 127.0.0.1

# Limit the number of simultaneous incoming connections. The daemon default is 1024
# -c 1024

# Lock down all paged memory. Consult with the README and homepage before you do this
# -k

# Return error when memory is exhausted (rather than removing items)
# -M

# Maximize core file limit
# -r
```

/var/log/memcached.log is empty.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring out what causes the errors?